# oauth2 + output access token print

Tags: python, oauth-2.0

i need output only access token : [xxxxx] oauth
Can u help me?

Code :

```
import requests  
    url = "xxxxy/v3/oauth2/token"
    
    payload = {
        "grant_type": "client_credentials",
        "client_id": "xxxxx",
        "client_secret": "xxxxx"
    }
    headers = {
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
    
    response = requests.request("POST", url, json=payload, headers=headers)
    
    print(response.text)
```

Output :
In output we can see access_token, token type and time to expire this key.
I want output only code from "access_token".

```
{
"access_token":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
"token_type":"bearer"
"expires_in":3600
}
```

Comment: Use `response.json()` to convert the response to a dictionary and you can access its "access_token"-key